# Firefox problem with float right

Tags: css, firefox, treeview, telerik-mvc

I use MVC3 and Teleki Treeview with specific formatting of the leaves. The formatting does not work on Firefox, when you use float right. You can see the code and compare the result with Firefox and other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/zAvvR/.

I want to make changes in the CSS but not in HTML code. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, which element isn't floating correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `float: left` the two siblings of the `div` with `float: right`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/zAvvR/1/

I used inline styles only because some were already there.

Comment: Thank you **thirtydot**, this is the solution of my problem.